# Use relative path as configuration value in application.conf

Tags: configuration, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to use SQLite with Play Framework 2.1, but I need to use a relative path that is relative to the root of the Play application.  How may I do that?

This is the related code in application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:/I/want/relative/path/"
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Does db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:I/want/relative/path/" work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create databse in the root of Play application, you should do following:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:sqlite_test.db"
```

I think if you want to use make database in folder such as `<PlayAppRootDirectory>/database/db_name.db`, you should provide the full absolute path in configuration value.

As the alternative, you may define environment variable of your Play application root directory and use its value on `application.conf`.

Play!Framework 2.x using **HOCON** format (Human-Optimized Config Object Notation) as the syntax for configuration file.

If you want to use Play!Framework root folder as the path of your database, you should do following:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
# The following line use HOCON format
db { default.url : "jdbc:sqlite:"${PLAY_APPS_ROOT}"/database/db_name.db" }
```

The configuration value above use HOCON syntax. Note that `${PLAY_APPS_ROOT}` is environment variable for **Play!Framework application root folder**. The database path actually the absolute path because you must define database path in **full absolute path**. You may read following resources for your reference:

1. [Typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)
2. [Play Documentation - Configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Configuration)